# How to find which flags were applied to git merge

Tags: git, git-merge

It appears that a git merge commit clobbered changes I made on one parent. Specifically, one parent contained a change (removing some lines from a file, and removing another file) and the other parent did not contain those changes. The result of the merge does not contain the changes. git show on the merge commit shows the removed lines being added into the file instead of removing those lines. git show does not show any change to the file which was removed.

I'm trying to understand why the merge result does not contain the changes. The merge commit message doesn't indicate any conflicts about the affected files.

My question is: Is there some way to discover what flags were applied to a merge? (Is there any flag that would not bring in the change from the parent that contains them? There wasn't a conflict about the affected files, so would --ours or --theirs have any effect?)

I'm worried that there might be other files for which changes were clobbered. I guess I will try some permutations of git diff to try to find those. Any advice on this point is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: Is there some way to discover what flags were applied to a merge?

The short answer is no.  When the merge is complete, the only things recorded as a result are in the commit object itself, which like any other commit, records your name and email address and time-stamp (as author and committer), the parent commit hashes (the two main inputs—the third input, the *merge base* commit, is computed automatically from these), your log message, and of course the final snapshot.

> (Is there any flag that would not bring in the change from the parent that contains them?

Yes.

> There wasn't a conflict about the affected files, so would --ours or --theirs have any effect?)

The `git merge` command itself doesn't have `--ours` and `--theirs`; instead, it has this very confusing set of options:

- `-s ours`: ignore the other commit(s) entirely; don't find a merge base; just make a merge commit that uses the current index contents.  (There will never be any conflicts this way, since Git doesn't even look at their changes.)
- `-X ours`: wherever there are conflicts, automatically resolve them using our changes.  If there are other unconflicted changes to the same file, use their changes to that file.
- `-X theirs`: wherever there are conflicts, automatically resolve them using their changes.  As with `-X ours` this only affects conflicted regions within a file; unconflicting changes are merged as usual.

If there are any unresolved conflicts at all, though, `git merge` stops in the middle of the merge, and gives you (the person doing the merge) full control.  At this point there *are* `--ours` and `--theirs` options, to `git checkout`.

> I'm worried that there might be other files for which changes were clobbered. I guess I will try some permutations of git diff to try to find those. Any advice on this point is welcome.

That's possible; note that you can run `git show -m` to split the merge into two separate virtual commits, one with parent #1 as its single parent (so that `git diff` will diff that parent vs the merge result), and one with parent #2 as its single parent (so that a second `git diff`, run by `git show -m`, will diff the other parent vs the merge result).

---

To see what the inputs to the merge were, run:

```
git merge-base --all <hash of first parent> <hash of second parent>
```

The output is the hash ID of the merge base(s).  Ideally there's only one hash ID here (if there are two or more, look up "virtual merge base").  Save that hash ID, then run:

```
git diff --find-renames <merge base hash> <hash of first parent>
```

and:

```
git diff --find-renames <merge base hash> <hash of second parent>
```

and you'll see what Git saw for the three inputs.

---

One other thing you can do pretty easily is *repeat* the merge.  If you get yourself a detached HEAD, pointing to parent #1, then run `git merge <hash ID of parent #2>`, you'll be repeating the same merge (maybe with different flags, since we have no idea what flags were used the first time).  **Be sure you have disabled `git rerere` before this, otherwise Git will *re*-use the *re*corded *re*solutions.** You can now re-resolve conflicts manually and commit.  The new commit will be a new detached HEAD, and you can now diff the contents of this commit vs the contents of the original merge commit:

```
git diff HEAD <other merge commit ID>
```

to see if you resolved things differently.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful.

Comment: By the way, to disable rerere for a merge, `git -c rerere.enabled=false merge`.